# How to validation embed video in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

please suggest me a gem or way validation embed video by ruby code. Example: Youtube Video, Google Video.

Comment: What to do you mean by validation?

Comment: I want user input correctly format. I will display error if they input incorrectly embed.

Comment: Maybe a better/easier/safer way would be to just have the user give you the Youtube url, and you generate the embed code for that. In addition to the simpler UI and code, you can also later change the embed code (different sizes and so on). Downside is that they can only use the services that you have thought of, and not style the embed code to their liking. Actually, both of that might be an advantage from your point of view (consistency, content control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in using [oEmbed](http://www.oembed.com/) to get the embed code of whatever the user pastes. Here's the [Ruby version](http://github.com/judofyr/ruby-oembed).

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple WYSIWYG editor would do the trick.  We use CKEditor but there are lots of ones out there.  A few are jQuery focused, if that is what you are looking into.

This would allow people to enter any embeddable thing, like google form, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I researched the topic and found https://github.com/dejan/auto_html extremely helpful. If you use something like

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  auto_html_for :body do
    html_escape
    image
    youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
    simple_format
  end
end
```

it automatically converts links and videolinks into embed code, very much like e.g. Facebook.